# When do dietary supplements need a hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, medicine

I am looking to purchase a [probiotic supplement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003THZ06A) ([ingredients](https://www.amway.com/en/ResourceCenterDocuments/Visitor/nutr-nut-nutr-v-en--DigestiveProbiotic_NI.pdf)) and was wondering if it requires a hechsher.

What are the criteria for a drug/supplement that would render it automatically kosher - or does not require any hechsher at all?

Comment: http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-medi-guide.htm

Answer (score 2):

Star-K [kosher guidelines](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/medicine/452/a-kashrus-guide-to-medications-vitamins-and-nutritional-supplements/) differentiate between sick people who, generally, can take whatever medicine is required, either normally (if their life might be in danger) or in an uncommon way (if they are not in danger and if no similar kosher medicine exists).

Probiotics are microorganisms that are believed to provide health benefits when consumed but they do not cure known diseases. Their claimed benefits include reducing gastrointestinal discomfort, improving immune health, relieving constipation, or avoiding the common cold but are not backed by scientific evidence. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probiotic))

Therefore probiotics fall in the category of supplements taken to maintain good health and for prevention. The rule for those is

> **One should make every effort to ensure that the product is either
>   kosher certified or contains all kosher ingredients.** If this is not
>   possible, a Rav should be consulted since in some instances non-kosher
>   products taken in an unusual manner may be permissible. Taking
>   non-kosher medication that requires eating in a normal manner (e.g.
>   non-kosher chewable tablets that taste good) is not permissible.

Now the specific product you indicate contains [natural grape flavor](https://www.amway.com/en/ResourceCenterDocuments/Visitor/nutr-nut-nutr-v-en--DigestiveProbiotic_NI.pdf) which is not kosher unless certified (see [OU's statement](https://oukosher.org/the-kosher-primer/) under XVI)

Luckily Star-K also list [kosher probiotics](https://www.star-k.org/resource/list/TB36XQA1/Pro-Biotic) (although your specific product is not there) so there is a kosher solution to your issue.